Why Isn't My Ring-LWE Decryption Working with Noise?
I'm developing a Ring-LWE encryption system for my study, but I’m facing some issues.
Here is the logic I’m using:
q = 2^20
n = maximum degrees

Generate secret, public keys
s = random coefficients polynomial
e, e0, e1 = polynomials with [-1, 0, 1] coefficients
p0, p1 = random coefficients polynomials, (-p0 * s + e) mod (x^n + 1) mod q

Encrypt
u = random coefficients polynomial
m = polynomial representing the plain message
c0, c1 = (p0 * u + e0) mod (x^n + 1) mod q, (p1 * u + m + e1) mod (x^n + 1) mod q

Decrypt
p = (c1 + c0 * s)

My questions are:

Is this logic correct?
When I remove e, e0 and e1, it works, but when I add noise, it doesn't.
I asked ChatGPT, and it said the modulus q should ignore the noise, but it doesn’t seem to work.
How can I ignore or manage the noise?

I am implementing this in Python. Below is my code:
def encrypt(message, public_key, params):
    (a, p) = public_key
    u = generate_random_binary_polynomial(params["n"])
    e0 = generate_small_noise_polynomial(params["n"])
    e1 = generate_small_noise_polynomial(params["n"])
    
    c0 = a * u + e0
    c0 = np.polydiv(c0, get_divider(params['n']))[1]
    c0 = mod_q(c0, params['q'])
    m_polynomial = convert_message_to_polynomial(plain, params["t"])

    c1 = p * u + m_polynomial + e1
    c1 = np.polydiv(c1, get_divider(params['n']))[1]
    c1 = mod_q(c1, params['q'])

    return c0, c1

def decrypt(cipher_set, secret_key, params):
    plain_set = []
    (c0, c1) = cipher_set

    decrypt_poly = (c1 + c0 * secret_key)
    decrypt_poly = np.polydiv(decrypt_poly, get_divider(params["n"]))[1]
    decrypt_poly = mod_q(decrypt_poly, params["q"])
    
    return convert_polynomial_to_message(decrypt_poly, params["t"], params["q"])


def convert_message_to_polynomial(m, t):
    poly = []

    while m != 0:
        poly.append(m % t)
        m //= t
    poly.reverse()
    return np.poly1d(poly)


def convert_polynomial_to_message(p, t, q):
    m = 0
    current_t_power = 1 
    
    for coeff in reversed(p.c):
        # if m > 100000: return -1
        m += coeff * current_t_power
        current_t_power *= t
    
    return m #  % q

thanks for help

p=m+ some small noise.  Normally you should maintain a scale parameter $\delta$ and let $m=\delta*m$. After decryption, divide $p$ with $\delta$, and the rounded result will equal m.
